# Detect server-side redirect within TWebBrowser control

Tags: delphi, redirect, http-redirect, twebbrowser

I'm implementing an OAuth 2.0 login, which uses a server-side redirect to 'http://localhost/?code=abcdef' to pass the necessary data to the client application.
But the `TWebBrowser.BeforeNavigate2` event is not fired in this case.

I've searched my head off, trying to find a way to detect server-side redirects (and handle them myself) within the TWebBrowser control (if possible at all).

As a workaround, I've implemented the `TWebBrowser.NavigateComplete2` event. But because there's no HTTP-server running at the localhost (usually) this takes some time before it's fired.

I'd like to detect the redirect before the webbrowser tries to navigate to it and parse the data of URL myself and skip navigating to the localhost.

Comment: Related: [Embedded IE browser: how to detect redirect before navigation completes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637939/) as `TWebBrowser` is an embedded IE browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `TWebBrowser` does not fire an event for a redirect. `OnBeforeNavigate2` is fired for the initial URL before the redirect, and then `OnNavigateComplete` is fired after the redirect. You can compare the URL provided by the two events to know whether a redirect happened or not.

However, if you enable the browser's `DOCHOSTUIFLAG_ENABLE_REDIRECT_NOTIFICATION` flag, you will then get an `OnBeforeNavigate2` event for a redirect, and can cancel the redirect if desired.

To enable the flag, you need to implement the [`IDocHostUIHandler.GetHostInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/aa753257) interface method.

If you are using 10.0 Seattle or later, `TWebBrowser` already implements `IDocHostUIHandler` for you, so just derive from `TWebBrowser` and override `GetHostInfo()` as needed.

Otherwise, for earlier versions, you can write a separate class that implements `IDocHostUIHandler`, and then you can  query the browser for its [`ICustomDoc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa753272) interface and call its [`SetUIHandler()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa753273) method.

Comment: Implementing the `IDocHostUIHandler` interface did the trick - Thanks. 
The value for `DOCHOSTUIFLAG_ENABLE_REDIRECT_NOTIFICATION` is `$04000000`

Comment: The question was also asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637939/embedded-ie-browser-how-to-detect-redirect-before-navigation-completes  (but I did not find it...)